# how to exit jenkins task by jenkinsfile normally without errors

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins file, I want to judge according to the variable input by the user. If the input value is not the expected value, I want the task exit normally, but No matter I use exit 0 or I use exit 1 in steps script like bellow

```
steps {
        script {
          if ( BUILD_BRANCH == "'uat'||'prd'" ) {
            echo "uat和prd环境 不允许重新构建！！"
            exit 0
          }
```

I will get the error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'exit' found among steps [acceptGiteeMR, addGiteeMRComment, ansiColor, archive, bat...
```

or If I wrap it with sh

```
steps {
        script {
          if ( BUILD_BRANCH == "'uat'||'prd'" ) {
            echo "uat和prd环境 不允许重新构建！！"
            sh "exit 0"
          }
```

When the command is executed, it does not report an error or exit

how can exit normally in jenkinsfile??

Comment: [By design](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html), `exit 0` is exit with no error, ie: normally. `exit $?` will exit with the last statement's return code, which would be the echo, so again, 0. You say, "if not expected value, exit normally" which would be `0` does not make sense.

Comment: I see what you mean, thx

Comment: Should have referenced this link on [exit and exit status](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html).

Answer (score 1):

like below can also get work!

```
steps {
        script {
          if ( BUILD_BRANCH == "'uat'||'prd'" ) {
              error "some msg"
          }
```

Comment: Maybe you want to incorporate my comments into your response as to how you realized your issue and came to your solution. So it helps someome else better, then mark as self-answered.

Answer (score 0):

Use `return` instead of `exit 0`.

Also, it will not exit the whole Jenkinsfile.  It is scoped to the closure which is running.  So `return` will skip that step.